# Deleting parent if children was clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, addeventlistener

I ran into a problem creating a ToDoApp

If I click icon should be removed li where the icon is.
I can't write a function that goes up to span and then to li and removes it.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset');

const addTask = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && input.value.length != 0) {
    let value = input.value;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.classList.add('material-icons');
    icon.textContent = "highlight_off";
    span.appendChild(icon);
    li.textContent = value;
    // span.setAttribute("onclick", `deleteTask()`);
    list.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(span);
    input.value = "";
  }
}

const deleteTask = (e) => {
  const element = e.target;
  console.log(element);
  element.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();
}

input.addEventListener('keydown', addTask);
list.addEventListener('click', deleteTask)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type text and click 'enter'">
  <ul>
    // Here is created li
  </ul>
  <button class="reset">CLEAR</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use closest

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset');

const addTask = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && input.value.length != 0) {
    let value = input.value;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.classList.add('material-icons');
    icon.textContent = "highlight_off";
    span.appendChild(icon);
    li.textContent = value;
    // span.setAttribute("onclick", `deleteTask()`);
    list.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(span);
    input.value = "";
  }
}

const deleteTask = (e) => {
  const element = e.target.closest("li");
  console.log(element);
  element.remove();
}

input.addEventListener('keydown', addTask);
list.addEventListener('click', deleteTask)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type text and click 'enter'">
  <ul>
    // Here is created li
  </ul>
  <button class="reset">CLEAR</button>
</div>
```